# How to get and restore current Settings in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to store/restore the values of the Settings panel. How can I do that?

I used the following but it was not successful.

In my scenario, I changed `Ghost hidden objects` and `Display Unit`, then:

```
let current_profile = NOP_VIEWER.profileManager.getProfileOrDefault();
let profile = new Autodesk.Viewing.Profile(current_profile);
```

After that, I changed Ghost hidden objects and Display Unit to some others again, then:

```
NOP_VIEWER.setProfile(profile);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is using `viewer.getState()`:

Storeing settings:

```
let current_state = NOP_VIEWER.getState();
let render_options = current_state.renderOptions;
```

Restore Settings:

```
let state = {renderOptions: render_options}
NOP_VIEWER.restoreState(state);
```

More Info: https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/tutorial-viewer_state.html